# What is relation between these integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know 
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$$
What is relation between it and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(4)}\frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{4e^x-e^{2x}}}dx$$
 Please guid me. I have sixteen years old
Why should we use $e^x=4t$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set $t=\frac{e^x}{4}$ , or $e^x=4t$ , thus  $4dt=e^x dx$

as $x\to-\infty$ then $t\to 0$ as $x\to\ln(4)$ then $t\to 1$
we have

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(4)}\frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{4e^x-e^{2x}}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(4t)}{\sqrt{16t-16t^2}}4dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(4)+\ln(t)}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt$$
$$I=\ln(4)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(t)}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt$$
Now set $t=\sin^2(\theta)$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin 2\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta\,\cos^2\theta}}d\theta=\pi\tag 1$$
similarly
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(t)}{\sqrt{t-t^2}}dt=4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin\theta)d\theta=\color{red}{-2\pi \ln(2)}=-\pi \ln(4)\tag 2$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ 
$$I=0$$
Indeed
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(4)}\frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{4e^x-e^{2x}}}dx=4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)dx+\ln (4)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2 dx$$

Comment: Please explain . I was confused.

Comment: I=0 is a relation!

Comment: I don't underestand your answer and I think that it is wrong

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: @H.R: I think that is not Behrouz' fault, his answer is pretty nice and clear ((+1)).

Comment: My teacher ' s answer is different.

Comment: Show us your teacher's answer.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks Jack -:)

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio Can you help me.

Comment: I showed this answer to my teacher. he told: It is correct. Sorry

Comment: سلام همشری! :) خعلی هم عالی!  به قول دوستان +1